# Updating text for numerous div's

Tags: javascript

I realize this might be a silly question, and I apologize in advance, but I was hoping there'd be an easier way to do this.
For example if I set the text of a div like so:

```
divOne.textContent = someVariable + "/5";
```

and I have about 60 divs that are like cells in one div container. Is there any way I can update the text values without manually calling it each time? The problem isn't when they change a cell one by one, it's when they hit the reset button. Is there a way to do it without writing 60 lines of text? Would the only solution be something like:

```
divOne.updateText = function() { this.textContent = someVariable + "/5"; }
```

and would that even be an ok solution? Creating 60 extra parameters each with a function overkill?

Any information on this subject is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit:

The reason why I didn't use the for loop to begin with is because each cell has a different max value, aka the 5 from someVariable + "/5" . I was asking after your comment though if it'd be better to just do something like this instead though:

```
someDiv[0].max = 5
someDiv[i].textContent = someDiv[i].points + "/" + someDiv[i].max;
//the above would be inside a for loop.
```

over doing the .updateText = function

Comment: Do all of the elements you want to change have something in common that you can grab them by, like a `class`, numerated `id`, etc?

Comment: Yes, its pretty much an array. so instead of divOne it's really someDiv = []; and then someDiv[0], someDiv[1] ..someDiv[60]

Comment: Why can't you just use a `for` loop?

Comment: because in " this.textContent = someVariable + "/5"; " the "/5" is different for each cell but I guess saving the max value possible of a cell would be better and easier than creating an entire function like I did above?

Comment: I really don't know what you're talking about. You're revealing your problem in small fragments. Please just describe what you need.\

Comment: Edited with more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you can just loop through your array using a `for` loop.

```
var someDiv = [];

// Fill array with elements

for (var i = 0, len = someDiv.length; i < len; i++) {
  someDiv[i].textContent = someDiv[i].points + "/" + someDiv[i].max;
}
```

Comment: since I'm calling someDiv so many times would you say in the reset function i do something like var sD = someDiv; to create a local var, would that 'speed' things up? since I'm calling it in 3 different places 60 times total 180 uses? or does it not matter?

Comment: Yes, since arrays are passed by reference, it would be faster to declare a local version of the array that you are working with than continually using the global array.